# Async fetch in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an asynchronous operation, fetching an array of items:

```
Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id })
```

Each item in that array has an ID, with which I need to perform a fetch of messages  and users for that item. For that I need a loop:

```
Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id })
        .then(bases => {
            for (let base of bases) {
            }
        })
```

Bsae.find() will return multiple items, hence the loop. The end of the GET method in node will have to return an array that looks something like:

```
bases: [
  {
   base: {info about base},
   users: 12,
   messages: 51
   },
   ...another base...,
   ...another base...
]
```

So far I have been unable to work multiple Promises (.find methods) into the loop, and have been unable to `serialize()` the information in a follow-up `.then()`. I have read other posts on stack overflow in which they suggested to use `async/await` functions, but this only let me perform one of the two methods (`baseUser.find()`). I don't know how perform these operations for each of the bases which are initially returned by `Base.find()`

**EDIT**:
For clarification, I need to call the following functions:
`Base.find` => returns an array of bases.
`BaseUser.find()` => which needs to be in a loop, because i need to `find` each item with an Id from the first `find`.
`Message.find()` => same as baseuser, messages get fetched with an ID from `Base.find()`.

**EDIT2**:
I now receive some data, but mostly useless for me to work with since I don't know of any way to data from the following:

```
async function fetcher() {
    try {
        const bases = await Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id });
        const baseUserPromises = bases.map(base =>
            BaseUser.find({ baseId: base._id })
        );
        return await Promise.all(baseUserPromises);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
}
fetcher().then(data => console.log(data))
```

result:

```
[ [ { created: 2018-09-03T14:05:39.968Z,
      acceptedMembership: true,
      isCreator: true,
      _id: 5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540604,
      userId: 'tester1',
      baseId: 5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540603},
    { created: 2018-09-03T14:05:43.357Z,
      acceptedMembership: false,
      isCreator: false,
      _id: 5b8d3fb7ccdfcc2e20540605,
      userId: 'tester2',
      baseId: 5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540603},
    { created: 2018-09-03T14:05:44.797Z,
      acceptedMembership: false,
      isCreator: false,
      _id: 5b8d3fb8ccdfcc2e20540606,
      userId: 'tester3',
      baseId: 5b8d3fb3ccdfcc2e20540603 } ],
  [ { created: 2018-09-03T14:11:48.802Z,
      acceptedMembership: true,
      isCreator: true,
      _id: 5b8d4124e96ca00eb42df8c9,
      userId: 'tester1',
      baseId: 5b8d4124e96ca00eb42df8c8 } ] ]
```

Double arrays since `Promise.all()` returns the first array with the resolved Promises, and then Mongo's `collection.find()` returns an array as well. So it's a Promise array, filled with two `find` arrays, filled with the results from `find`

Comment: You want to call `.find()` in two occasions? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @anjuc I added clarification in the Edit

Comment: @Helle and what is exactly your problem with that result? Do you want to have the result as flat array, that contains all results?

Comment: @Helle `await Promise.all` does not return `array with the resolved Promises`. It returns an array of the values those Promises resolved to. So you have an array containing the arrays you get from each individual `find`.

Comment: @t.niese I need usable data for Redux. When looking at the second edit, I kinda knew this info already. I meant what you clarified, but thanks for making it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)?

```
 try {
    const bases = await Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id });
    const baseUserPromises = bases.map(b => BaseUser.find({}));
    const result = await Promise.all(baseUserPromises);
  } catch (e) {
    // TODO: handle errors
  } finally {
    // DO: something
  }
```

First get all the data you need, and then you can build up the array of object you want to return.

**EDIT**
Updated code

```
function getBasePromise(base) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const users = await BaseUser.countDocuments({ baseId: base._id });
    resolve({
      base,
      users,
    });
  });  
}

async function fetcher() {
    try {
        const bases = await Base.find({ creatorId: req.params.id });
        const baseUserPromises = bases.map(base => getBasePromise(base));
        return await Promise.all(baseUserPromises);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get a populated return from Promise.all. It's just empty arrays. Unless I made a mistake when customizing for my situation this does not work

Comment: @Helle can you update your question with the code you tried with?

Comment: Updated my original answer

Comment: @Helle i have updated my answer with a snippet that might do what you are looking for, i didn't test it though. Let me know

Comment: the update solves the issue. Except I can't serialize the new object. i believe this is because the message length and user length isn't part of my Model. Any idea how I'd fix this?

Comment: @Helle open a different question for that with correct tags, and if this issue is solved mark it as solved so future reader can see it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179372/discussion-between-sid-and-helle).

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand from your question, you want to get base array and use it for two async functions. You can do it as follows.

```
const sampleFunc = async function(){
  try {
    const bases = await Base.find(YOUR_REQUIREMENT);
    const baseUsers = await BaseUser.find(YOUR_REQUIREMENT);
    const messages = await Message.find(YOUR_REQUIREMENT);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

This method has to be work.

Comment: `bases` is the array of bases. You can loop through it and call the second await statement. Likewise.

Comment: I need to conduct the second fetch (`BaseUser.find()`) with information that comes back from the first fetch. The way you wrote it doesn't do that ?